# How to use overlays in bubble diagram?

Tags: beamer, overlays, smartdiagram

I am creating a bubble diagram using

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to use overlays to show it step by step.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to use the `animated version`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\smartdiagramanimated[bubble diagram]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution works. But when I use `pstricks' package it does produce an unwanted overlay (repeats complete frame each time)

Comment: @Jitendra Does it also happen if you compile with `xelatex`? On my machine, the issue arises only if I compile with pdflatex, but this does not make much sense if one loads pstricks.

Comment: Well, this is great !  Was wondering if the animation could be made clockwise... posted a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490742/146828) on that.