# Is it possible to overlay bubble diagrams clockwise?

Tags: beamer, overlays, animations, smartdiagram

While the [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432776/146828) provided the solution to my first question (*whether the bubble diagram could be overlayed at all ?*), the next branching question naturally arose :

- Is it possible to animate the bubbles **clockwise** ?

Example borrowed from [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432776/146828) :

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\smartdiagramanimated[bubble diagram]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the code. Even though most (animated) diagrams have a `clockwise` option, the bubble diagram doesn't. However, the code for this one is rather short, so I copied and "hacked" it. You have now optional keys `orientation` (`-1` means `clockwise`) and ``start angle` that you can adjust to your needs.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{Partha/.cd,
start angle/.initial=0,
orientation/.initial=1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BubbleDiagramAnimated}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation},
Partha/.cd,#1]
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
\node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
}{%false
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Partha/start angle}+%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Partha/orientation}*360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
\node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->](module\xi)
at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem};
}%
}%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\BubbleDiagramAnimated[orientation=-1,start angle=-120]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can make it more reminiscent of the other keys by defining a `clockwise` code.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{Partha/.cd,
start angle/.initial=0,
orientation/.initial=1,
clockwise/.code=\tikzset{Partha/orientation=-1,Partha/start angle=-120}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BubbleDiagramAnimated}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation},
Partha/.cd,#1]
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxsmitem\xi}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\actualnumitem{\maxsmitem-1}
\foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
\ifnumequal{\xi}{1}{ %true
\node[bubble center node, smvisible on=<\xi->](center bubble){\smitem};
}{%false
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xj}{\xi-1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\angle}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Partha/start angle}+%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Partha/orientation}*360/\actualnumitem*\xj}
\edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xj}}
\node[bubble node, smvisible on=<\xi->](module\xi)
at (center bubble.\angle) {\smitem};
}%
}%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\BubbleDiagramAnimated[clockwise]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second solution *is* easy-to-remember, but at the same-time more application-specific. I liked the first solution more because it's more *flexible*, and can start from *any angle*-- that's something I learnt as a bonus from your answer !

Comment: @ParthaD. Thanks! You can of course combine them, i.e. these things are not mutually exclusive, e.g. `\BubbleDiagramAnimated[clockwise,start angle=150]{Machine Learning,
  Supervised, Unsupervised, Reinforcement}` also works (but the order matters here, if you set `start angle` first, it ill be overwritten.)

Comment: Oh-- so, `clockwise` replaces `-1` ?! Then, that's fantastic... I misundertood, or rather under-understood :)